# MySQL 8: Create Collections via DDL

Tags: mysql, ddl, mysql-8.0, connector-net, sqlmigrations

I’d like to be able to create MySQL Document Store Collections via simple SQL DDL statements rather than using the X-Protocol clients.

Is there any way to do so?

Edit: I’ll try and clarify the question.

Collections are tables using JSON datatypes and functions. That much is clear.
I would like know how I can create a Collection without using the X-Protocol calls *and* make sure that the aforementioned collection is picked up as an actual Collection.

Judging from MySQL workbench, collection tables have a _id blob PK with an expression, a doc JSON column and a few other elements I do not recall at the moment (might be indexes, etc).

I have no means to tell via the Workbench whatever additional schema/metadata information is required for a table to be considered a Document Store Collection, or if the mere presence of an _id and doc columns are enough.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: There is not enough data for a meaningful response.

Comment: @Akina which kind of data are you looking for, so that I may add it in the question? I’m not sure what’s missing.

Comment: The collection part of the document store api is a mapper for the [json datatype and json functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) (or vice versa), e.g. creating a collection is basically the same as creating a table with a json column using sql syntax. You'll need to add more details if you have a specific problem or question.

Comment: @Solarflare I added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All "x-api" instructions are directly mapped to sql syntax. When you e.g. run `db.createCollection('my_collection')`, MySQL will literally just execute

```
CREATE TABLE `my_collection` (
  `doc` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `_id` varbinary(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS
     (json_unquote(json_extract(`doc`,_utf8mb4'$._id'))) STORED NOT NULL,
  `_json_schema` json GENERATED ALWAYS AS (_utf8mb4'{"type":"object"}') VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `$val_strict` CHECK (json_schema_valid(`_json_schema`,`doc`))
      NOT ENFORCED
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

You can run the corresponding sql statements yourself if you follow that format.
The `doc` and `_id` (with their type and the given expression) are required, the `_json_schema` is optional, the check too (and only added since MySQL 8.0.17). Since MySQL 8, no additional columns are allowed, except generated columns that use `JSON_EXTRACT` on `doc` and which are supposed to be used in an index, see below (although they don't actually have to be used in an index).

Any table that looks like that - `doc` and `_id` with their correct type/expression and no other columns except an optional `_json_schema` and generated `JSON_EXTRACT(doc,`-columns - will be found with `getCollections()`.

To add an index, the corresponding syntax for

```
my_collection.createIndex("age", {fields: [{field: "$.age", type: "int"}]})
```

would be

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`my_collection` ADD COLUMN `$ix_i_somename` int
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(doc, '$.age')) VIRTUAL, 
   ADD INDEX `age` (`$ix_i_somename`)
```

Obviously,

```
db.dropCollection('my_collection')
```

simply translates to

```
DROP TABLE `my_collection`
```

Similarly, all CRUD operations on documents have a corresponding sql DML syntax (that will actually be executed when you use them via x-api).

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not accepting this as an answer sooner, did not receive any notification.